# stair riser variation between stairs and landings

Tags: stairs

I'm designing a stairs in a very tight space that has an upper landing and a lower landing, each segment requires a 90 deg turn.  If the landing riser heights are different from the main run - does this present a hazard?  If so - why?

Presently the upper landing is 10.5" drop, followed by steps of ~9.5", and back to 10.5" on the lower.  The stair runs are 11.5"

Comment: My thought is - once the walking gait pattern in broken - you effectively have a different stairs.    For example, the stairs in my home go to a small landing at the front door - then there is a step out of the front door that drastically different height.  10.5 is a large drop (although the step stool I use is 14") - but you fall into the landing - not the stairs.
I'm aware of the code - but by code a stairs are not possible - so I've been using a ladder.  Code is also based on average size of people - how well would code stairs work for small or large people?

Comment: What do you mean by the "landing risers"? Are you referring to entire stair runs between landings, or the single rise above or below a landing?

Comment: @isherwood The first step down would be 10.5", followed by a 90 deg turn, followed by steps ~9.5", followed by a 90 deg turn, followed by what I call 2 steps to the floor.  Maybe riser isn't the correct word - so I call them drops.

Comment: I think the answer has been given - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38128/do-stairs-need-to-be-the-same-height-after-landing

Comment: If that's a duplicate, please delete your question.

Comment: "Rise" is the distance between treads. "Riser" is the lumber or other material that acts as the wall at the rear of the tread.

Answer (score 4):

Code says risers can’t be more than 8” high and can’t vary from the largest to smallest by more than 3/8”.  (See IRC R311.7.5.)

Treads can’t be less than 9” and can’t vary by more than 3/8”.

Comment: The question was does it present a hazard - not what does code say.

Comment: There are “exceptions”: If it’s just access to mechanical space, spiral stairs, etc.